# Como cambio el wallpaper de la pantalla de bloqueo?

Tags: android

Básicamente estoy haciendo una aplicación de wallpapers, al momento de cambiar el fondo de pantalla o background solamente cambia el de la pantalla de home, pero la pantalla de bloqueo no, he buscado en diferentes foros pero no encuentro una solución correcta.

Código donde obtengo el Bitmap desde un XML en un servidor:

```
URL url = new URL(url_down);

            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());

            if (colocarWallpaper) {

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {

                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(img);


                } catch (Exception error) {
                    Log.e("prueba", "colocar wall error: " + error);

                }
                return null;

            }....
```

Gracias de antemano por la colaboración.

// SOLUCION

```
if (colocarWallpaper) {

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                int flag_lock = WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK;

                try {

                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(img);
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(img, null, true, flag_lock);//**

                } catch (Exception error) {
                    Log.e("prueba", "colocar wall error: " + error);

                }
```

** Utilizando el WallpaperManager y con esta linea logre hacer el cambio de fondo de la pantalla de bloqueo pasandole el img (Bitmap)

Comment: y cual el problema que obtienes al realizar esto? Es importante revisar el LogCat, en este caso seguramente tienes un NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 3):

Perfecto.
Este seria el método que hace la magia. Ver [aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean)).

```
int setBitmap(Bitmap fullImage, Rect visibleCropHint, boolean allowBackup, int which)
```

Ahora explicaré como hacer la implementacion correcta.

Lo primero, agregar los permisos necesarios:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
```

Ahora el método que se encargará de establecer el fondo de pantalla según parametro:

```
/**
 * Cambia el fondo de pantalla del home y/o lock screen desde un mapa de bits(Bitmap).
 *
 * @param activity    Actividad del contexto
 * @param bitmap      Mapa de bits para ser aplicado como fondo de pantalla
 * @param statesApply Lista booleana que contiene estados para aplicar un fondo de pantalla. Este
 *                    array debe se ser de solo dos elementos, es decir:
 *                    boolean statesApply[] = new boolean[] {whichSystem, whichLock};
 *                    El primer elemento de su indice indica al whichSystem y el segundo al  whichLock,
 *                    este orden no puede ser alterado por ningun motivo.
 *                    Si {@param statesApply} es null se aplicará para ambos, es decir:
 *                    whichSystem(HomeScreen) = true y whichLock(LockScreem) = true
 *                    NOTA: Este parametro tendrá efecto apartir de la API 24 y posterior.
 * @param fixed       Determina si al momento de aplicar, éste será de tamano fijado por la resolucion del dispositivo o no:
 *                    true --> se aplica con la misma resolucion del dispositivo
 *                    false --> se aplica dependiendo de la resolucion del wallpaper si es muy alta será scrollable.
 * @return true si se aplicó correctamente el fondo de pantalla o false si hubo algún error.
 */
public static boolean setWallaper(Activity activity, Bitmap bitmap, final @Nullable boolean[] statesApply, boolean fixed) {
    boolean success = false;
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(activity);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    final int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    final int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    if (bitmap != null) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                boolean whichSystem = true;
                boolean whichLock = true;
                if (statesApply != null) {
                    whichSystem = statesApply[0];
                    whichLock = statesApply[1];
                }
                int which = 0;
                if (whichSystem) which |= WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM;
                if (whichLock) which |= WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK;

                //wallpaperManager.clear();
                if (fixed) {
                    wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                }
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, which);
            } else {
                //wallpaperManager.clear();
                if (fixed) {
                    wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                }
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            success = true;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError | IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

Finalmente la forma de llamar el método anterior para establecer el fondo de pantalla:

```
boolean whichSystem = true, whichLock = true;
boolean statesApply[] = new boolean[]{whichSystem, whichLock};
boolean fixed = false;

Utils.setWallaper(MainActivity.this, bitmap, statesApply, fixed);
```

Resultado final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, edite la pregunta y agregue la solución que encontré, un poco mas corta jejeje pero veo tu código y entiendo que abarca todas y cada una de las opciones necesarias para cambiar el wallpaper (con el SYSTEM y el LOCK).

Comment: El alertDialog o Fragment que aparece ahi, el que tiene las opciones para seleccionar donde cambiar el wallpaper, lo creaste tu en un layout aparte ? o lo crea el sistema automaticamente ?

Comment: Es un dialogFragment creado, de hecho el sistema no te genera niguna vista.

Comment: Entiendo, pensé que lo daba el sistema como por ejemplo, cuando solicitas algún permiso para leer o editar algún archivo de la memoria, crea un cuadro de dialogo y lo hace el sistema, nosotros no programamos esa vista exactamente, pero gracias @Jose Diaz muy útil tu respuesta.