# Como agregar imagen como Wallpaper en Android

Tags: android

En un dispositivo Android podemos agregar una imagen como fondo de pantalla ("Wallpaper"),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Cuales son los métodos para agregar programáticamente una imagen como
>   fondo en un dispositivo Android?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Agregar una imagen como Wallpaper en Android**.

Primeramente debes registrar el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Para agregar asignar una imagen como wallpaper, puedes agregar una imagen almacenada en los recursos del proyecto como Wallpaper o una imagen desde un url de internet :

#### Agregar como wallpaper una imagen almacenada en los recursos del proyecto.

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
   try {
       myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.androide); //*Agrega imagen de recursos como Wallpaper
   } catch (IOException e) {         
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Agregar como wallpaper una imagen de internet.

También se puede agregar una imagen desde una url, y asignarla como Wallpaper, en esta segunda opción se debe realizar el proceso de descarga en un thread diferente al principal para evitar el error [**NetworkonMainThreadException**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13521/error-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-en-usar-httpurlconnection-de-andro), para evitar esto se debe usar un Thread, Asynctask, Handler, etc.

Este es un ejemplo de un método el cual llamamos de esta forma:

```
setWallpaper(" Url imagen ");
```

Este es el método completo:

```
private void setWallpaper(final String urlImage) {
    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(urlImage);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(myImage);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.e("Loading Image", "Error : " + error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma de cambiar el fondo de pantalla de un teléfono programáticamente es mediante la clase [WallpaperManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html).

Ésta clase cuenta con varios métodos para realizar cambio de fondo de pantalla, obtener el fondo de pantalla actual, borrar el fondo de pantalla, etc.

En esta otra respuesta que dí, hice mensión de como hacerlo, cambiar el fondo de pantalla del home y lock screen, redimensionar según la densidad de la pantalla, ponerlo fijo, etc. Verlo desde [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115618/42302).

La otra forma de cambiar el fondo de pantalla es en base a un Intent. Un ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA)
                    .setDataAndType(mUri, "image/*")
                    .putExtra("mimeType", "image/*")
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, null),
                    REQUEST_CODE_CROPANDSETWALLPAPER);
```

Aquí lo que hace es solicitar un selector de las applicaciones que concuerdan con la action del intent. En base a ello el usuario puede escoger con que aplicación cambiar el fondo de pantalla.
[image: Cambio de fondo de pantalla por Intent]

Si tienes alguna duda házmelo saber.